# How to customize animation of an ActionBar?

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar

By applying show() or hide() on an Activity's ActionBar, it gets slided in or out, respectively. Instead of this default sliding animation I need a custom animation with fading in and fading out behavior.
How to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to accomplish this ?

you can use toolbar and animate it like an ordinary view.